# How to use query clause in EXPDP

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, expdp

I am exporting data of a table through EXPDP by using the below command

```
nohup expdp \"/ as sysdba\" directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=EXP.dmp logfile=EXP.log version=11.2.0.4 TABLES=CRM.CATEGORIES QUERY='"where bank_id='43'"'
```

Getting the below error

> ORA-31693: Table data object "CRM"."CATEGORIES" failed to load/unload
>   and is being skipped due to error:
>
> ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEPOPULATE callout
>
> ORA-01722: invalid number

If I remove the query parameter from the export command, it works fine. I have tried changing the version parameter to different values but still getting the same error
The BANK_ID column in the table is of NVARCHAR2 data type.
I can't use EXP as it is blocked on the db. Oracle version is 12.1.0.2.0 for both source and destination db.

Comment: What is the datatype of CRM.CATEGORIES.BANK_ID?

Comment: @APC Its NVARCHAR2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try to alter your query filter in this way:

```
QUERY=(CRM.CATEGORIES:"WHERE bank_id='43'")
```

please be aware of the `:`

**Edit**
I Managed to make it work in this way:

```
expdp \"/ as sysdba\" dumpfile=DATA_PUMP_DIR:test.dmp tableS=CRM.CATEGORIES QUERY='(CRM.CATEGORIES:"WHERE bank_id=43")'   logfile=DATA_PUMP_DIR:test.log
```

Comment: Doesn't work, getting error  - syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Same error - error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEPOPULATE callout

Comment: under this error there must be more specific explaination

Comment: The complete message is
ORA-31693: Table data object "CRMUSER"."CATEGORIES" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEPOPULATE callout
ORA-01722: invalid number
Master table "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded

Comment: It doesn't makes sence. try to encapsulate your value with TO_NCHAR(). and if this still wont and if your table is not too big. I suggest you to create another table with filtered result and get expdp for it. you can do table_remap when importing

Answer (score 0):

Use a par file file, much easier

with

...
QUERY="where bank_id=43"

Cheers
Brian

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me in Solaris (Date value used in query parameter)

expdp xxxxx/xxxx dumpfile=test_table.dmp logfile=test_table.log tables=scott.TEST directory=DUMDIR query=scott.TEST:\"where IMG_SAVE_DTTIM \<\ \'01-\JAN-\19\'\"

For more infor Refer.Doc ID 277010.1